# headers in listview

Tags: android, listview, header

I have a ListView and I have two tables from database which is categories and items and i want to display them in the ListView as headers(Category)and items below each header.
i don't know why i can't do it dynamically i used this tutorial 
http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

and works fine but the data is static i want to get data from database and display it

any help please .Thank you

here is what I was trying to do but the data didn't bind

```
     protected void BindOrederItemList(final int order_id) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //select all categories from order items where order_id =??
        //select items where category=??
        String Url="http://192.168.3.113/mywebservices.php?op=GetOrderCategory&lang_id=1&order_id="+order_id;
        GetNetworkData.OnPostExecuteListener listener=new GetNetworkData.OnPostExecuteListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (result!=null)
                {
                    try
                    {

                 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                 ArrayList<Integer> category=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) 

                    {
                             //   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            id=e.getInt("order_id");
                          if (id==0)
                        {

                        }

                      else
                       {

                         cat_name=e.getString("cat_name");
                          cat_id=e.getInt("cat_id");
                         category.add(cat_id);
                         //select orderitems where cat_id??



                         BindCatItems(cat_id, id);

                       }

                    }



                       Catadapter.addSection(cat_name , new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), catItemsList, R.layout.list_item,
                                new String[] {"item_name"},
                                new int[]{R.id.list_item_title}));

                        Log.i("Bind item", "CAT SIZE "+catItemsList.size());



                 order_items_list.setAdapter(Catadapter);
                        }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        };

        try
        {
        GetNetworkData task = new GetNetworkData(Url,null,listener);
        task.execute();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    protected void BindCatItems(int cat_id,int order_id)

    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String Url="http://192.168.3.113/mywebservices.php?op=GetOrderItems&lang_id=1&cat_id='"+cat_id+"'&order_id="+order_id;
        GetNetworkData.OnPostExecuteListener listener=new GetNetworkData.OnPostExecuteListener() 

        {

            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (result!=null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                         catItemsList.clear();
                         JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);


                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                int id=e.getInt("item_id");
                                if (id==0)
                                {

                                }
                              //  String s = e.getString("posts");
                            //     JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(s);


                                else
                                {
                                map.put("item_id",String.valueOf(e.getInt("item_id")));
                                map.put("oi_id", String.valueOf(e.getInt("oi_id")));
                                map.put("item_name", e.getString("item_name"));
                                map.put("quantity",String.valueOf( e.getString("quantity")));
                                map.put("price", String.valueOf("price"));
                                catItemsList.add(map);
                                }
                            }

                            Log.i("Bind", "CAT SIZE "+catItemsList.size());

                             Log.i("Add Section","section "+cat_name);



                          /*  ItemsAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), catItemsList, 
                                    R.layout.list_item,
                                    new String[] {"item_name"},
                                    new int[]{R.id.list_item_title});
                             */
                             //order_list.setAdapter(adapter);
                            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        try
        {
        GetNetworkData task = new GetNetworkData(Url,null,listener);
        task.execute();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }
```

Comment: any help please no one know the answer